# What is the mistake in this singleton object creation code

Tags: c++, class, singleton

In this, i am trying to copy singleton object to another object. Though i have overridden = operator, its giving me some problem. Kindly help.

```
 class singleTon
        {
        public:
            static singleTon*  InitInstance()
            {
                if(singleTonObjPtr== NULL)
                {
                singleTonObjPtr = new singleTon;
                }
                return singleTonObjPtr;
            }

            singleTon* getObject()
            {
                return singleTonObjPtr;
            }

            singleTon(const singleTon& singletonObj)
            {

            }

            void operator =(const singleTon& singletonObj)
            {
                  return;
            }

        private:
            singleTon()
            {
                i = 50;
                singleTonObjPtr = NULL;
            }

            ~singleTon()
            {
            }

            int i;
            static singleTon* singleTonObjPtr;

        };

        singleTon* singleTon::singleTonObjPtr = NULL;


        int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
        {
          singleTon *singleTOnPtr =NULL;
          singleTOnPtr = singleTon::InitInstance();
          singleTon *singleTOnPtr2 = singleTOnPtr->getObject();

          singleTon obj3 = *singleTon::InitInstance();
    }
```

Comment: "giving me some problem" So, what is the problem ?

you have `InitInstance` method to access your singleton object. no need to have `getObject`. if you call `getObject` before `InitInstance` you will get a null pointer.

Comment: What is *some* problem? And well Using a singleton in the first place indicates a truck load of problems already.

Comment: And trying to copy a singleton makes no sense - it's not a singleton any more if you've copied it...

Comment: What is the problem you are getting ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, operator= is the assignment operator, so you are assigning, not copying. Your assignment operator returns `void`, but it should return a `singleTon&`. But you really have to ask what the meaning of assigning to a singleton is. For example:

```
singleTon a = singleTon::InitInstance(); // single instance
singleTon b = singleTon::InitInstance(); // same instance
a = b; // assignment, but a and b really are the same instance, so what's the point?
```

And, for a singleton, there should no default-construction:

```
singleTon b; // this should not be allowed
b = a; // so this makes no sense
```

Comment: There should actually no public construction at all.

Comment: @Paranaix Well, it depends on definitions. I would consider the call to singleTon::InitInstance() to be a public construction, although there is no public constructor. But I agree that there should be no public constructors.

Comment: @Juanchopanza, Here  "singleTon obj3 = *singleTon::InitInstance()" i'm trying to copy the object. It says private members are not accessible as error. code does not compile. Why?

Comment: @LLL The error is due to the destructor being private, as Mike Seymour has explained. I also agree with his explanation of why when you allow copying and assigning then you don't have a singleton anymore.

Comment: But in my code, i have override copy constructors. Ultimately i will not copy anything.. its just a reference right.. so it should be a singleton

Comment: @LLL it is good that you make it behave as a singleton, but it is a bit strange semantically to have "copy" and "assign" for a singleton. I have bad experiences with such semantics in the past, because you can be led to believe that you are making a new object when you aren't. But at the end of the day, you have to measure the pros and cons of each approach according to your situation :-)

Answer (score 1):

It might help if you read (and post) the compiler error. I get:

```
test.cpp:37: error: ‘singleTon::~singleTon()’ is private
test.cpp:55: error: within this context
```

where line 37 is the declaration of the private destructor, and line 55 is the point in `_tmain` at which the code tries to create and destroy an object, requiring a public destructor.

If you want to be able to create and destroy multiple copies of your confusingly-named-not-quite-singleton-thingy, then you'll need to make the destructor public. For this simple example, you can do that by removing the destructor altogether; the implicit constructor will be public, and there are no members that need non-trivial destruction.

Comment: Oh, Thanks Mike... but the above class is singleton right?... i just want clarification

Comment: @LLL: The term "singleton" usually refers to a class that has only one instance, especially if you're talking about the misguided and much abused Singleton (anti-)pattern described in the otherwise mostly excellent Design Patterns book. By making it copyable, it can have multiple instances, so "singleton" really doesn't describe it accurately.